# Android layout not displaying button below list view

Tags: listview, android-linearlayout

I have 2 similar projects that pulls contact address from DB and shows in list view. I need to select contact and click a button. Below is the layout file (identical that I used in both projects). One project shows list with button where as the other shows list, not the button.
Any recommendations please?

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:stackFromBottom="false"
    android:transcriptMode="normal"
    android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"  >

</ListView>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/SelectBtn"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/selectBtn"
    android:layout_weight="0" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code,

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:stackFromBottom="false"
    android:transcriptMode="normal"
    android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"  >

</ListView>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/SelectBtn"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Ok"
    android:layout_weight="0" />

</LinearLayout>
```